# can we have username and password authentication in SSIS SMTP mail task?

Tags: ssis, smtp

I need to use office 365 cloud server to send mails, which needs username and password to authenticate. But, I am not able to find such option in SSIS SMTP mail task. Could someone help me out here?

Comment: SMTP in SSIS only supports anonymous authentication and Windows Authentication.  Link to documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/connection-manager/smtp-connection-manager?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Is there a way around instead of using 'Script Task' in SSIS?